# Hashtags scrolls incorrectly

Tags: html, css, height, hashtag

I have a page which has 2 faux columns with equal height (applied negative margin -9999px and positive padding 9999px). However, if I try to jump to the middle of the page by hashtag of an id, the page seems to scroll all the way down and I can't see the top part of the page. It seems to be very weird and happen in all browsers ...

Can anyone help me this?

Comment: Can you put the code up on jsfiddle or some similar service?

Comment: It seemed to have problem when combine negative margin method with hashtag. I had to change back to multiple column layout using background image.